# Integrating Administrator and Sentry

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, administrator, cartalyst-sentry

According to http://gastonheim.blogspot.com/2013/09/laravel-integrar-sentry-y-administrator.html , I tried to merge Sentry with Administrator (frozennode). I expect when I login, after check I redirect to the administrator Admin panel, but it doesn't happen. I changed the code for `routes.php` but it searches an Admin page in my view. How can I connect the login page to administrator Admin page ?

```
Route::post('user/login', function()
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email'    => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    $remember = Input::get('remember') ? true : false;

    $user = SentryTest::authenticate($credentials, $remember);
    $adminUrl = Config::get('administrator::administrator.title');

    return View::make($adminUrl); /// in this part? which path I should give it?
});

Route::post('user/logout', function()
{
    SentryTest::logout();

    return Redirect::to('user/login');
});

Route::get('Admin',function(){

    return View::make('hello');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out just by change the code

```
  $adminUrl = Config::get('administrator::administrator.title');

    return View::make($adminUrl);
```

to

```
 return Redirect::to('admin');
```